# Fastest way to implement subset in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, set

So according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_algebra_of_inclusion) (Proposition 8) the following statements are equivalent:

- A `is subset of` B
- A `intersection` B equals A
- A `union` B equals B
- A `difference` B equals the empty set

Scala gives us the union, intersection and difference operators, as well as set equality.

Given that, which would be the most efficient (runtime) way to implement a `subset` function in Scala?

Comment: What would the signature of the `subset` function be?

Comment: You mean instead of using the built-in `a.subsetOf(b)` method (which is linear in the length of `a`)?

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Also, the code is open source, so you can just see how they're all implemented.  (They're all linear.)

Comment: I would guess that the `A.diff(B).isEmpty` variant is the fastest because the `isEmpty` check is constant compared to the `equals` comparisons which is linear in the other cases. But this doesn't change anything with respect to the overall linear complexity.

Comment: @TillRohrmann, the `diff`  will have to do the same  `equals` comparisons?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, the implementation of `diff` should be similar to the other approaches in terms of complexity. However, I was talking about the complexity of the succeeding comparison of the resulting set.

Comment: Why would that be faster than subsetOf?